# Content under md-sidenav Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I created a navigation component that hold a md-sidenav and md-toolbar.
At first when I clicked on a link in the sidebar, it redirected me to the component I wanted, but the navigation dissappeard. 
After, I fixed it by putting my navigation component also in the component I wanted to be redirected. This time it worked, but now the component is under the md-sidenav and not on the side. What could it be? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing is probably not setup correctly. My guess is that your `router-outlet` contains the navigation component, and overwrites the entire page with the component you are navigating to.

If you want to maintain the same page layout with navigation and all, but fill out part of the page with the new content, do something like this (contrived example):

```
<header-component></header-component>
<navigation-component>
    <a routerLink="/myNewComponent"></a>
</navigation-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- This turns into whatever you want 
                                     in the main part of the page.
                                     I.E. home page, the new page, etc -->
```